Is there a way to enable keyboard and mouse at login?
I recently tried to sign in to my Mac Pro 1,1 that is running 10.6.8 with the correct password but the computer would not recognize the password as valid. After many failed password attempts and reading about certain key combinations to reset PRAM etc. I believe I inadvertently disabled the keyboard and mouse because neither are responsive at the login screen or the computer locked me out (which I didn't think was possible). The keyboard and mouse I am using are wired apple products by the way. Here are the things i have tried so far:
Option-Command-P-R = not successful never heard a chime twice 
Option key 5 times = no effect 
use another keyboard = no difference 
use another mouse = no difference 
use another USB port = no difference 
replace PRAM coin cell battery = no difference 
I was able to remove the drive and change the password using terminal on another Mac Pro, so the problem is not hard drive specific. No matter what I do, I cant get a response from the keyboard or mouse on the computer in question.

If you can boot the drive on another Mac Pro, set up auto-login, then you can test if the peripherals work once logged in. I don't know any way to intentionally disable before boot.

Same keyboard and mouse work on another Mac?

Yes the same keyboard and mouse work on another Mac.

Set-up Auto Login is this the same as removing the password? Assuming I can get past the login screen but the keyboard and mouse are still unresponsive...what recourse do I have at that point?

Tetsujin..I set up auto-login on the hard drive via another computer and was able to login sans a password but the keyboard and mouse are still not responsive.
